# How to stop AsyncTask in infinite loop?

Tags: android, loops, android-asynctask, infinite

I have AsyncTask and my progress in background is in infinite loop. But I need to stop AsyncTask when user stop my app or go back from my app (my app go to foreground). How can I do it?

**Solution:**

> private boolean done = false;

```
private class CurTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
        protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
            while(!done){
                DefaultCurProgress();           
                publishProgress();
            }
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...unused) {
            textCur = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_cur);

            SharedPreferences myPrefs = MyActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String prefNameDefaultCur = myPrefs.getString(DefaultCur, "");

            textCur.setText(prefNameDefaultCur); 
        }
}

@Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        done=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        done=false;
    }
```

Comment: Like in any Thread, it should be possible to use a flag ``while (keepRunning == true)``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a method within your AsyncTask that tells it to end. Something like so:

```
private class CurTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
    private boolean done = false;

    public void quit() {
        done = true;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
        while(!done){
            DefaultCurProgress();           
            publishProgress();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how can I call quit() when my Activity or app is stopped?

Comment: From your Activity's `onPause()` method call it?

Comment: Yes, I thought it, but I didn't want to remake your code. Now it works, thanks. Code will be up.

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean member variable and use that in your while condition instead of *true*.

Then when you need to cancel it you can just call an instance method to set this variable to false, the doInBackground method will return and the task will finish.